# While writting file using fwrite, the output file attach file size in the last line of file

Tags: php, csv, fopen, fwrite

I'm trying to write and download CSV file using php. So every time file is created, file size is being attached in the last line. Like, if file size is 10kb, then the file result is

```
    Viwed Date  Product Name    Viwed Item  Username    User Email
    16-04-2012  i3 Primary  Mathematics neha_new    neha_new@mailinator.com
    16-04-2012  i3 Primary  III         neha_new    neha_new@mailinator.com
    16-04-2012  i3 Primary  i3 Primary  neha_new    neha_new@mailinator.com
```

Here is the code

```
if($_POST['report_format']=='csv') {
  $csv_rows[] = array('Viewed Date','Product Name','Viewed Item','Username','User Email');
  $da = db_query($sql);
  while($data = db_fetch_object($da)) {
    $partid = db_query("select name from term_data where tid=".$data->ptid);
    $product_name = db_result($partid);

if($data->type=='term') {
  $catid = db_query("select name from term_data where tid=".$data->tid);
  $cat_name = db_result($catid);
  }  elseif($data->type=='node') {
    $term_node = node_load($data->tid);
$cat_name  = $term_node->title;
  }
  else {
$term_node = node_load($data->tid);
$cat_name  = $term_node->field_read_image_field[0]['filename'];
  }
  $u = user_load($data->uid);
  csv_rows[] = array(date('d-m-Y', $data->date), $product_name, $cat_name, $u->name, $u->mail);
}
foreach($csv_rows as $csvrow) {
  $csvdata .= implode(',',$csvrow)."\n";
}
$file_path = $base_url."/sites/default/files/";
$fp = fopen("sites/default/files/user_csv/account_report.csv", "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($fp, $csvdata,strlen($csvdata)-1);
fclose($fp);

$url = $base_url.'/sites/default/files/user_csv/report_csv.php';
header("Location: ".$url);

    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your code snippet. It'll be easier to debug what's going on :)

Comment: Those are not email address's you have validation problems [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), please make an effort when asking a question, clearly explaining what you have done and tried. Then we will be delighted and encouraged to help, else you get comments like above ;p